# Send an Email with hosted Blazor Webassembly

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, smtp, blazor-webassembly

I have a hosted Webassembly project and I am trying to send an email. All the tutorials I could found are for Blazor Server projects. But due to security issues I can't use the same code from my client. So somehow I have to implement the logic to send the email on my server side and use it on my client side. I tried using injection, so I created a Service on my server like this

```
public interface ISendEmailService
    {
        void SendEmail(string sendTo, string subject, string body);
    }
    public class SendEmailService : ISendEmailService
    {
        public void SendEmail(string sendTo, string subject, string body)
        {
            
            using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
            {
                    
                ...
                using (SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
                {
                    ...    
                }
            }
        }
            
        
    }
```

and I registered it in my Server Program.cs

builder.Services.AddTransient<ISendEmailService, SendEmailService>();

and then I tried to inject my service in my client page, but I couldn't.  My quesiton is, is my approach wrong and what could be other possible ways to send an email with hosted webassembly.

Comment: You have two distinct program, the client and the server. When you register a service in one, it isn't available in the other.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blazor client side send an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66297523/blazor-client-side-send-an-email)

Comment: Yes, I know they separate. My initial thought was, that I can create the service in the server and then register it and inject it in the client. But the service in my server couldn't be reached from my client to register it there. So that's why I was asking if there are any other possibilities.

Comment: Yes, client and server are distinct programs with distinct services. You need the client call the server that send the email.

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: This doc can help : [Call a web API from Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?pivots=webassembly&view=aspnetcore-6.0)